# Window media player in windows mobile 6 application developement

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5, windows-mobile-6, windows-mobile-6.1

I am developing windows mobile 6.5 application, in which i have to use window media player 
to play videos in the application.

Please help me or give reference of any website which contains information about using window media player in windows mobile 6.5 application development.

Any help appreciated 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

[There's an MSDN article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446515.aspx) entitled "Hosting ActiveX Controls in the Compact Framework".  It specifically uses the Media Player control as an example.